# Mongoose - required validator not running by function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose

I'm passing a function to required validator in mongoose schema, but it's not firing if i don't pass any value to the field.

In documentation says the following:

> Validators are not run on undefined values. The only exception is the required validator.

Reference: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html

If I pass a function is it not applied?

**EDIT - Sharing the code:**

My field definition:

```js
field: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Model',
      required: !isBlock,
      autopopulate: true
    }
```

The function that isn't firing:

```js
function isBlock() {
  return this.type === 'block'
}
```

Comment: Please share code ??

Comment: Please share code ??

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar shared ;)

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `isBlock()` and not just referencing it? `!someFunction === undefined` so you are setting `required` to `false` when you really want whatever the result of `isBlock()` is.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting a reference code match with this otherwise Show your code.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const cryptoRandomString = require('crypto-random-string');

const userSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        trim: true,
        type: String,
        required: [true, "firstName is required!"],
        validate(value) {
            if (value.length < 2) {
                throw new Error("firstName is invalid!");
            }
        }
    },
    lastName: {
        trim: true,
        type: String,
        required: [true, "lastName is required!"],
        validate(value) {
            if (value.length < 2) {
                throw new Error("lastName is invalid!");
            }
        }
    },
    email: {
        unique: [true, "Email already registered"],
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Email is required"]
    },
    mobile: {
        unique: [true, "Mobile Number alraedy available"],
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Mobile Number is required"],
        validate(value) {
            if (value.length !== 10) {
                throw new Error("Mobile Number is invalid!");
            }
        }
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Password is required"],
        validate(value) {
            if (value.length < 6) {
                throw new Error("Password must be atleast 6 characters!");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Debugging I saw that the problem was with the '!' operator in the function call, changing the code to the under I solved my problem.

```
required: function () { return !isBlock(this.type) }
```

Comment: Thanks for following up with this, it helped me